# XCode/Swift cannot change text label position

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, position, label

Im trying to randomly change the position of a label on my screen and its not working. however, this same code works if i open a new xcode project. also, note the print statement at the bottom of my code. it does in fact print a different location every time the function is called, but does not change the position of the label.

```
func displayCurrGoal() {

    self.label.text = "heyyy"

    // Find the labels width and height
    let labelWidth = self.label.frame.width
    let labelHeight = self.label.frame.height

    // Find the width and height of the enclosing view
    let labelViewWidth = self.label.superview!.bounds.width
    let labelViewHeight = self.label.superview!.bounds.height

    // Compute width and height of the area to contain the labels center
    let labelXwidth = labelViewWidth - viewWidth
    let labelYheight = labelViewHeight - viewHeight

    // Generate a random x and y offset
    let viewXoffset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(labelXwidth)))
    let viewYoffsset = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(labelYheight)))

    // Offset the labels center by the random offsets.
    self.label.center.x = viewXoffset + labelWidth / 2
    self.label.center.y = viewYoffset + labelHeight / 2


    //test if coordinate is changing every time func is called 
    println(self.label.center.y) }
```

also, autoformatting is not enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct approach so u must be using cocoapods or something. if so, the imageview u are using is probably fixed, so u need to try something different...

Answer (score 0):

- Do you see the label presented on the screen?
- Do you see the text being changed to "heyyy"?
- What does `label.constraints()` return?
- Try setting position to hardcoded numbers

Normally `view.center.x = 100` works

Comment: Ok so I have more info... I have 2 buttons on the screen. 1 button controls an NSTimer, and the other moves that label around randomly. if i hit the button that moves the label before i start the timer ( and leave out the self.label.text = "heyyy" ), it moves around fine, but the second i hit the other button to start the timer the label goes right back to (x,y) ... also, when i tap the button to change the label.text, it changes it to "heyyy" only for a split second and then goes back to the default "button" text. similarly, when i have the self.label.text present, it wont move button pos

Comment: any chance you are performing this on the background thread? comment out all the code and set position as soon as you get the reference to the label (e.g. viewDidLoad if it happens inside of the view controller)

Comment: meaning that you might perform operations not from the main thread. UIKit (and UILabel is a part of it) can be accessed only on the main thread. So if you used any of the concurrency techniques such as dispatch_async or 
performSelectorInBackground:withObject: or anything else, changes that you perform are not guaranteed to have a consistent result